# Print a number with probability P

Tags: probability

Say we have two numbers 0 and 1.
We need to print 1 with probability p.

for example. if p= 0.8,
print 1 with a probability of 0.8 and 0 with a probability of 0.2.

I want to know what different approaches I can take.
What kind of an algorithm can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no language or technology is stated, here is the pseudocode:

```
q <- random (uniformly distributed) number between 0 and 1
if q < p print "1"
else print "0"
```